# Does jboss act as both application and web server?

Tags: java, jboss, extjs4, webserver, appserver

I am creating a JavaEE Web Application which uses ExtJS4(Extended Javascript) for the GUI and Postgres database. I am planning to use the JBoss7 server. But I had a doubt that whether the JBoss 7 will act both as App Server and Web Server..?? Can anyone please help me with this..?

Also, I wanted to know if there is anything else that is required for developing the application?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final    AS Certified Java EE 6 Full Profile

So you can think that Jboss AS 7.1.1.Final acts as an application and web server (it has a Servlet and EJB container)

Take a look on http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/javaee6technologies-1955512.html

Comment: sorry..but I did not find anything about JBoss in that link

Comment: can you help me with any other info?

Comment: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final AS is Java EE 6 certified so it implements all the jsrs mentioned in doc http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/javaee6technologies-1955512.html